# Filter by File Path in OSX Finder

Tags: macos, finder

I have a series of folders, each contains 3 folders. Inside each of these three folders is a copy of the same image with the same filename, but they're optimized differently like so.

```
   |-Event1
   |---optimized
   |---originals
   |---thumbnails
   |-Event2
   |---optimized
   |---originals
   |---thumbnails
   |-Event3
   |---optimized
   |---originals
   |---thumbnails
```

I'd like to find only those photos in the optimized directories which contain "486" in their filename and copy those off to a different folder.

I've tried searching in finder. I can easily narrow the search down by file type (Image) and filename contains "486", but can't seem to figure out how to limit it to only those images within the "optimized" folder. I thought "Document Container" might be the trick, but didn't work. Help appreciated!

[image]

Comment: In Terminal, `cp Event*/optimized/*486* destination/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tripleee answer did the trick, though it doesn't answer how to do this in the finder (which is totally okay with me).

`$ cp Event*/optimized/*486* destination/`